# Can I include a static class in C# so I don't have to type the class name to use its static functions?

Tags: c#, static-methods

In VB.NET I had a static class called ArrayExtensions which contained static functions like `Join(Of T)(ParamArray arrays As T()()) As T()`.  They were in a Module.  I didn't need to include the module; I could just type `Join(array1, array2, array3)` from any other class in the project.

Now that I'm trying out C#, I have the same static function `T[] Join<T>(params T[][] arrays)` in a static class `ArrayExtensions`.  I can't seem to figure out how to escape having to write `ArrayExtensions.Join(array1, array2, array3)` every time.  I tried `using ArrayExtensions` which did not work, unlike VB.NET.

Is there any way I can just type `Join(array1, array2, array3)` in C#?

I debated changing it to `T[] Join<T>(this T[][] arrays)` and using `{array1, array2}.Join()`, only to discover that unlike VB.NET C# forces me to write `new [] {array1, array2}.Join()`.  Couldn't the compiler figure out whether braces contained statements or array items?  Disappointing.

Comment: You can use extension methods instead: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any way I can just type `Join(array1, array2, array3)` in C#?

Unfortunately, no. This is a fairly frequently requested feature. It would be nice to be able to do something like:

```
using System; // the namespace
using System.Math; // the type
    ...
    x = Sin(Abs(Max(...
```

instead of

```
    x = Math.Sin(Math.Abs(Math.Max(...
```

This is a perfect example of a "nice to have but completely unnecessary" feature. It has never been compelling enough to actually make it high enough on the list to be implemented. We have a list of "nice to have but completely unnecessary" features literally longer than your arm, and we can't implement more than a couple of them in any release, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

So you want to enter a random method name, and want the compiler to search through all classes in all known namespaces (i.e. all namespaces that are being "using'ed") for a method with that name? Why?

You could create an extension method from it, so you can call `array1.Join(array2)`:

```
T[] Join<T>(this T[][] array1, T[][] array2)
```

Comment: Because I'm used to this feature in VB.NET and understood how to take advantage of it.  Now I miss it in C#.

Comment: The only thing I don't like about this is that I have to put the first array in a very syntactically different place.  It works, but it's not as nice.

Comment: @jnm2 I understand you miss it, but if there's one argument I can provide: I've encountered this in Delphi too, and it did _not_ help debugging. If you see a method being called this way, you won't know which one is being called until you follow it. It might be in the current class, in another class in the current file or (and that's where the fun starts) in any class in any namespace (as long as it's being used/imported). Adding a little more verbosity really helps reading the code later.

Comment: I haven't run into that particular problem yet, but what I do use already which would solve that problem is right click > Go to definition.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to do something similar is to make an extensionmethod like the one below. Include classes with "using statement" is not possible.

Make a method like this.

```
public static class ArrayExtensions
{
   public static Array MyOwnArrayJoin(this Array array1, Array array2)
   {
       //Do the Join and return Array
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C# doesn't support modules. 
You could use extension methods for T[][]

```
public static class ArrayExtension 
{
    public static T[] Join<T>(this T[][] self, params T[][] arrays)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

this will let you do this:

```
array1.Join( array2, array3 );
```

Anyway, I think this is supported by Linq:

```
array1.Union(array2).Union(array3);
```

Comment: `Union` discards duplicates, so I wouldn't want it here.  But maybe I'll go with the previous example.